# Is $a*b = a - b + 1$ a binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Possible binary operation is $a*b = a - b + 1$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

I don't believe this is a binary operation in any way. A counter example is when $a = 1$ and $b = 5$, then the result of $a*b, -4 \notin \mathbb{Z}^+$

I also checked whether it was commutative or associative. It failed both tests. However, I don't think I actually needed to check for those properties.

A binary operation can be neither associative or commutative, but still be considered a binary operation I suppose, so all that is necessary to be a binary operation is if the result is in the same set?

Comment: Well, it's certainly not a binary operation from the positive integers to the positive integers, for the reason you mention.

Comment: Is there an original problem statement you could cite? This seems to be missing context. If you allow the term "binary operation" to apply to operations taking positive integers but producing (possibly negative) integers, then it is one. If not, then not. So what is your definition of "binary operation"?

Comment: To be precise you should ask if it is a binary operation *on* $\Bbb Z^{+},\,$ since otherwise the question is ill-specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a binary operation because a binary operation on a set $X$ is a mapping (any mapping) from $X\times X$ to $X$. As you correctly pointed out, your mapping does not mapp from $\mathbb Z_+\times \mathbb Z_+$ to $\mathbb Z_+$, because it maps $(1,5)$ to $-4$ which is not in $\mathbb Z_+$.

Checking for commutativity and associativity, however, is meaningless in the context of the question "is this a binary operation?". There exist binary operations which are neither commutative nor associative, but they are still binary operations. Testing for commutativity has no effect on the question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Sure, a "binary operation on a set $X$" is what you say. But I think it is rather common to also call maps $X\times X\to Y$ binary operations. (Like the dot product on $\mathbb R^n$ for example, also listed by Wikipedia as a binary operation)

Comment: @Christoph True, there is some overlap in the definition. But I think that in the context of introductory algebra (which, based on the question, is the correct context), we usually mean the standard definition of binary operations on a specific set (i.e. the ones that can result in the set becoming a group)

Comment: Yes, @5xum definition is the one my book is using. My teacher does not give very descriptive questions and I feel that I am left guessing to the true intention behind them most of the time. On the other hand, my textbook is, in my opinion, overly verbose!